# Nearest Neighbours of OOV are also OOV - FastText

Tags: python, nearest-neighbor, word-embedding, fasttext

I am trying to get the nearest neighbors of an out-of-vocabulary (OOV) word in fasttext, however, it appears that also the nearest neighbors are OOV as well? This is the code I'm using:

```
    # get the intersection of the vocabularies of both models
    all_vocab = []
    all_vocab.append(model1.words)
    all_vocab.append(model2.words)
    # get the intersection of all vocabulary
    common_vocab = list(set.intersection(*map(set, all_vocab)))
    print('len of common vocab: {}'.format(len(common_vocab)))
    # len of common vocab: 112251

    nnsims1 = model1.get_nearest_neighbors(w, k)
    nnsims2 = model2.get_nearest_neighbors(w, k)
    
    nn1 = [n[1] for n in nnsims1 if n in model1.words]
    nn2 = [n[1] for n in nnsims2 if n in model2.words]
    
    print(len(nn1) == len(nnsims1)) # False
    print(len(nnsims1), len(nn1)) # 50 0
    print(len(nn2) == len(nnsims2)) # False
    print(len(nnsims2), len(nn2)) # 50 0
```

My interpretation of that is that if the word is OOV, then its vector is an aggregation of some sub-words, and since this "aggregated representation" is not in the vocabulary, then it has no neighbors from that vocabulary. However, how are the neighbors for an OOV word generated? I can't seem to find any explanation from FastText's documentation.

Comment: Where do your `model1` & `model2` come from?

Comment: @gojomo they are both FastText models

Comment: Did you train them yourself, and how? Or download them from someone else's training?

Comment: @gojomo I trained them myself on the corpus I have - I used SGNS

Answer (score 0):

Models that are trained separately will *not* have compatible coordinate spaces, unless you take some other steps to force that to be the case. (There's enough randomness in the model initialization, & training, & effects of different training data & even arbitrary thread-ordering during multithreaded training, that each training session is essentially creating its own separate, but internally-sensible, 'space'.)

So even a simple word like `'hot'` could be in an arbitrarily different place, and the relative distances/directions are only meaningful inside the *same* model.

Thus I suspect what's happening (without totally stepping through your code) is that for any OOV word from one model, all of the nearest in-vocabulary words (of that same model) are still OOV in the *other* model.

To the extent the language/word-senses in both corpora are compatible, you may want to train all texts/words into a single combined model.

(There are other 'alignment'/translation techniques you could also consider, if the models have some set of shared 'anchor' words that you are willing to stipulate *should* have identical coordinates - but that's a more complicated & probably 'looser' process than just getting all the data/words into one unified model.)

Comment: Thank you for this precise explanation, but just to make it clear I am finding OOV nearest neighbours in the **same** model not in a different one

Comment: Aha. You need to be checking if the word `n[1]` is in the model's `.words], *not* the `(similarity, word)` tuple. EG: `nn1 = [n[1] for n in nnsims1 if n[1] in model1.words]`. Or more clearly via destructuring: `nn1 = [word for score, word in nnsims1 if word in model1.words]` (Sorry, I mostly work with a different FastText API in Gensim, so didn't notice this at 1st.)

Comment: Yes thats exactly it. No worries and thanks for the guidance